# Finishing activity doesn't reset it

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I'm building a game  with a restart button and a home button. When I press the home button it finishes the game activity and opens the home activity. However, when I open the game activity again, the activity looks just like when I finished. What I have read is that finish() will destroy the activity and it's progress and open a new instance when I open it again. What can I do about it? Thanks! (Here's the code to finish the activity and start the home activity)

(ActivityManager is my own class to start an activity)

```
((Activity) context).finish();
ActivityManager.StartActivity(context, ActivityManager.AvailibleActivities.MainActivity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that it was just some variables that didn't reset and after making a reset() function that resets those variables it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `recreate()`. This works for me.